# How do I keep my text on one line in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, select

I’m using JQuery 1.11.  I’m trying to create a styled select menu that automatically adjusts its width based on the width of the largest element.  I have

```
<div class="profileField">
    Birthday<br/> 
    <select id="user_dob_2i" name="user[dob(2i)]">
<option value="">Select Month</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
</div>
```

and then I’m using the following CSS

```
.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 220px;
  height: 42px;
}

.select-styled {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 11px 12px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.select-styled:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 10px;
}

.select-styled:hover {
  background-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.select-styled:active, .select-styled.active {
  background-color: #737373;
}

.select-styled:active:after, .select-styled.active:after {
  top: 9px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}

.select-options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #737373;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.select-options li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-indent: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #676767;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}

.select-options li:hover {
  color: gray;
  background: #fff;
}

.select-options li[rel="hide"] {
  display: none;
}

ul.select-options {
  max-height: 15em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

However, what I’m unable to figure out is how to keep all the default option text in one line.  If you look at my JSFiddle — http://jsfiddle.net/m5bxbx6d/1/ , you’ll notice that the “Select Month” bleeds over into two lines on Mac Firefox.  On Chrome and Safari, the text is all on one line.  How can make it all on one line for Firefox as well?

I don't want to hard-code a width because I want this code to be generic enough to apply to any menu I want to style.

Comment: I'm not using a Mac but does making the width bigger fix this? `select { width: 300px }`

Comment: I clarified my question.  I don't want to hard-code a width because this code shoudl be able to apply to menus that contain different options.  The one I used in the Fiddle is just an example, but they won't all have the same options.

Comment: Oh the dynamic width set on it is different, probably just need a different way to get the width

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: i simplified your js so it is easier to work with, http://jsfiddle.net/m5bxbx6d/43/ I added a wrapper to your select and grabbed its width instead. The wrapper is display inline block. Obviously you have to tweak this for your code. I still see a difference of 4px between FF and Chrome but it's closer

Comment: THanks but when I cut and paste your width code into my Fiddle, the menu now takes up the entire screen -- http://jsfiddle.net/m5bxbx6d/53/ .

Comment: @Mike I mentioned I simplified your fiddle. Your js does a bunch of things which affect the outcome. It won't work if you just paste it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are breaking because you're not making the width wide enough.

A quick fix is to use non breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`). You can either hardcode them of add them programmatically like so:

```
$(selectMenu).children('option').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
});
```

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/m5bxbx6d/56/)

The real fix is to just fix your width. Your calulations are wrong because you're not using `outerWidth()` and because you're adding classes after the measurement. Add your classes first so you get an accurate measurement, and use `outerWidth()` instead of `width()` and it should work.

```
$this.addClass('select-hidden');
var paddingWidth = $paddingCalculator.outerWidth() + 10;
$paddingCalculator.remove();
var selectWidth = $this.outerWidth() + paddingWidth;
```

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/m5bxbx6d/57/)

Answer (score 3):

Just add the !important in your width of div.select,

**CSS:**

```
.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 220px !important;
  height: 42px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m5bxbx6d/58/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `white-space` property to control how text is line wrapped:

```
.select-styled {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This fixes the line break, but now the text flows beneath the triangle down arrow... you can add some padding to the `.select` container to carve out space for the arrow so it won’t overlap:

```
.select {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just modified these two lines in your javascript and it seems it is working fine (Firefox + Mac):

```
var paddingWidth = $paddingCalculator.outerWidth() + 15;

var selectWidth = $this.children().width() + paddingWidth;
```

*The padding one was just for aesthetics*

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this happens because you're setting the width of the new wrapper element `<div class="select">` making calculations based on the width of the original `select`: the jQuery `width()` function on select elements returns different results in Firefox and in Chrome. So you end up with something like `style="width: 111px;"` in Firefox and `style="width: 134px;"`in Chrome.

You can use outerWidth to have more consistent results, but they will differ slightly too, because the width calculation on non-styled `select` rendered by the browser is not reliable.

As a simple solution, I think the CSS only approach proposed by @keithjgrant is definitely the most elegant, but I would add also a `white-space: nowrap;` to `.select-options li`. N.b.: it is not a complete solution because you could have very long texts in one of the other `option` elements, it would overflow and result partially hidden.

```
.select-styled {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 11px 12px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;

    /* this */
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.select-options li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 12px 0;
    text-indent: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid #676767;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in;

    /* and this */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

As more advanced solution I would rethink the way your replacement are styled (that 220px hardcoded value also is not a good solution).

---

I also suggest you to have a look at a good replacement library I used in the past called [Select2](https://select2.github.io/).